# How to search between user specific dates?

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures

I am working on vehicle booking system and have two tables named:
 VehicleBookingStatus and VehicleDetails

They are linked with primary-foreign concept by Vehicle_Id being common.

My vehicle 1 (ID) is booked between 5 Jan to 10 Jan. So I need a join query for the two tables which can give result based on availability.

For example: Vehicle is not available for 3 conditions.

1. date is 3 jan to 7 jan
2. date is 7 jan to 13 jan.
3. date is 3 jan to 15 jan.

I have created SP like below, but it is not giving me desired output:

```
Select  
VehicleDetails.Vehicle_Id,
VehicleDetails.Vehicle_Name,
VehicleDetails.Vehicle_Capacity
   from VehicleDetails 
   left join VehicleBookingStatus on  
   VehicleDetails.Vehicle_Id = VehicleBookingStatus.Vehicle_ID
where  
   ((@UserDate NOT between VehicleBookingStatus.Assign_Date and VehicleBookingStatus.Return_Date)
AND
   (@UserEndDate not between VehicleBookingStatus.Assign_Date and VehicleBookingStatus.Return_Date))
OR 
   ((@UserDate not between VehicleBookingStatus.Assign_Date and VehicleBookingStatus.Return_Date)
and (@UserEndDate > VehicleBookingStatus.Return_Date))
```

@UserDate and @UserEndDate will be provided by user.

Thanks.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: What datatype are the Assign_date and Return_date?

Comment: Given a date for each variable, what data do you see being returned?

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
Select  v.Vehicle_Id, v.Vehicle_Name, v.Vehicle_Capacity
from VehicleDetails v left join VehicleBookingStatus b 
     on v.Vehicle_Id = b.Vehicle_ID
where b.Assign_Date is null or NOT (
     b.Return_Date between @UserDate and @UserEndDate OR
     b.Assign_Date between @UserDate and @UserEndDate OR 
     (b.Assign_Date < @UserDate AND b.Return_Date > @UserEndDate) )
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've modified my answer to reflect RBarryYoung's suggestion below:

```
select 
  vd.Vehicle_Id
, vd.Vehicle_Name
, vd.Vehicle_Capacity
from VehicleDetails vd
left join VehicleBookingStatus vbs on vd.Vehicle_Id = vbs.Vehicle_ID
where NOT (@UserDate <= vbs.Return_Date AND @UserEndDate >= vbs.Assign_Date)
```

Comment: Close, but not quite.  It should be more like `where NOT (@UserDate < vbs.Return_Date AND @UserEndDate > vbs.Assign_Date)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I like your approach and I think I've seen something like it before but I don't think it handles overlapping dates correctly.  I created a small sample data set to see how it fit with this logic and it would return a car as being available if there is an overlap.  For instance, let's say a car has been booked from 1/1/2013 to 1/31/2013.  If we enter in a UserDate of 1/18/2013 and a UserEndDate of 1/2/2013, it would try to schedule the car because only one of the dates comparisons is false.

Comment: First, this is absolutely the correct equation, its has long been established as the correct way to check for overlapping ranges (for at least 40 years). Secondly, that's an invalid User date range, you've got the end before the beginning.  Finally, even so, the algorithm does still work on it because the @UserDate(1/18/2013) is less than the Return_Date(1/31/2013) and the @UserEndDate(1/2/2013) is greater than the Assign_Date(1/1/2013), so the "and" condition is true, and the "NOT" then excludes it from the WHERE.

Comment: Thanks RBarryYoung for taking the time to explain this.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the query to return details for vehicles that are available for booking for a specified period.

The bookings that ends before @UserDate, or that
starts after @UserEndDate are no problem.

Thus the condition for a vehicle being not available is that
it has bookings that both starts before or on @UserEndDate, and
also ends on or after @UserDate.

The query should then be:

```
SELECT VD.Vehicle_Id,
       VD.Vehicle_Name,
       VD.Vehicle_Capacity
FROM VehicleDetails VD 
LEFT JOIN VehicleBookingStatus VBS
ON  VD.Vehicle_Id = VBS.Vehicle_ID
AND VBS.Assign_Date <= @UserEndDate
AND VBS.Return_Date >= @UserDate
WHERE VBS.Assign_Date IS NULL
```

If a new booking can start on the same day that the previous one ends, the `=` signs can be removed.